# is there a max. external screen resolution in a windows 7 starter netbook?

Tags: windows-7, netbook, external-display

I have a samsung netbook n220, and when I connect it to my external samsung display t260 (26", 1900 x 1200), the resolutions available in the windows 7 control panel tops with 1680 x 1050.

Is that some limit on the starter version of win7?, an issue of drivers (it has the out of the box drivers and settings)?, or is some limit at hardware level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That laptop has an Intel N450 Atom processor and an Intel GMA 3150 display chipset. The maximum VGA output resolution is 1400x1050. I'm guessing you got lucky with some sort of scaling/stretching (wide screen monitor?) to get 1680x1050. Sorry.

Source: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/quick-reference-guide-to-intel-integrated-graphics